# get_terms() doesn't return empty terms even though hide_empty is false

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I can't manage to make `get_terms()` to return the empty terms and I've tried it in a number of ways.

Here's the code:

```
$terms = get_terms('device',array('hide_empty' => 0));
foreach($terms as $term) {
        if($term->parent == 0) {
            if($i++ != 0) echo '</optgroup>'; echo '<optgroup label="'.$term->name.'">';
            $id = $term->term_id;
            $args = array("child_of"=>$id);
            $this_term = get_terms('device',$args);
            foreach($this_term as $the_term) { 
                $term_name = str_replace($term->name,'',$the_term->name);
                echo '<option value="'.$the_term->term_id.'">'.$the_term->name.'</option>';
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried all the possible ways:

```
$terms = get_terms('device',array('hide_empty' => false))
$terms = get_terms('device',array('hide_empty' => 0))
$terms = get_terms('device',array('hide_empty=false'))
$terms = get_terms('device',array('hide_empty=0'))
```

Also tried the last two ways without `array`. Nothing seems to be working. It returns all the terms that have posts, but no empty one.

Comment: Hace you tried with the paramenter `'get' => 'all'`?

Comment: I've found the culprit. I was using `get_terms()` twice and I forgot about it, so I didn't add `hide_empty` to the second function.

Comment: Ok, glad to hear that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use the `hide_empty` argument for `$terms`, but not for `$this_term` inside your loop.

Also, with the way you're generating your select, it would be a lot more efficient to just query top-level terms for the main loop:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'device', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0 ) );
```

And then drop `if($term->parent == 0) {...` inside your loop.

Comment: Yeah, this looks much better. I've already made the change. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem.

I'm using `get_terms()` twice, once for the parents and once for the children. It seems like I didn't add `hide_empty=false` to the one that gets the children.